# Minimal Polynomial of $\phi : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ Defined by $\phi(v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n)^t = (v_n, \dots, v_2, v_1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials

I have a question about minimal polynomial (and characteristic polynomial) of the following.

> We have the endomorphism $\phi: V \to V$ defined by $\phi(v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n)^t = (v_n,\dots,v_2,v_1)^t,$ where $V$ is the $\mathbb R$-vector space $\mathbb R^n.$

My idea was to use the standard basis and build the matrix regarding this basis. I just wanted to ask if this is the right way (or if there is an easier way) to solve the problem.
I am sorry that I wrote it like that, but this is my second post on Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The map takes the transpose of the row vector $\mathbf v = (v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n)$ to the row vector $(v_n, \dots, v_2, v_1)$? This doesn't seem to make sense. On the one hand, you are viewing $V = \mathbb R^n$ as the $\mathbb R$-vector space of row vectors, but at the same time, you are viewing it as the $\mathbb R$-vector space of column vectors. Both of these are valid -- but not at the same time.

Comment: I am sorry, I made a mistake - it should be the transpose.

Comment: Both transpose, then? That makes sense. Yes, I would start by writing down the matrix of $\phi$ with respect to the standard basis consisting of $\mathbf e_j = (\delta_{1,j}, \delta_{2,j}, \dots, \delta_{n,j}),$ where $\delta_{i,j}$ is the Kronecker delta.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to write down a matrix. Obviously, it holds $(\phi\circ \phi)(\mathbf v)=\mathbf v$ for all $\mathbf v\in V$. Hence, the minimal polynomial is a divisor of $x^2-1$. There are three candidates: $X-1$, $X+1$ and $X^2-1$. For $n=1$ it is easy to check, that $\phi(\mathbf v)=\mathbf v$ for all $\mathbf v\in V$. So, the minimal polynomial is $X-1$.
For $n>1$ observe, that for $v_1\neq \pm v_n$, we have $\phi(\mathbf v)\neq\pm\mathbf v$. Hence, the minimal polynomial is $X^2-1$

Comment: The question also asks for the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: This is a much better solution! One more question: the characteristic polynomial is ((X)^2 - 1)^n?

Comment: No, the characteristic polynomial has the degree $n$.

Comment: Yes, i need to learn how to format text here. Thanks!

Comment: Hello :) You're right, i haven't read this. Observe, that $\phi(\mathbf{e}_i)=\mathbf{e}_{n+1-i}$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$. Hence, we get $\phi(\mathbf{e}_i+\mathbf{e}_{n+1-i})=\mathbf{e}_i+\mathbf{e}_{n+1-i}$ and $\phi(\mathbf{e}_i-\mathbf{e}_{n+1-i})=-\mathbf{e}_i+\mathbf{e}_{n+1-i}$, It follows, that $\mathbf{e}_1+\mathbf{e}_{n}, \mathbf{e}_2+\mathbf{e}_{n-1}, \mathbf{e}_{\lfloor (n+1)/2\rfloor}+\mathbf{e}_{\lceil (n+1)/2\rceil}$ are linearly independent and elements of the eigen space of $1$. It yields $\dim(E(1))\geq \lfloor (n+1)/2\rfloor=\lceil n/2\rceil$.

Comment: Almost the same holds for $\lambda=-1$. We have $\mathbf{e}_1-\mathbf{e}_{n}, \mathbf{e}_2-\mathbf{e}_{n-1}, \mathbf{e}_{\lfloor (n+1)/2\rfloor-1}-\mathbf{e}_{\lceil (n+1)/2\rceil+1}$ are linearly independent and elements of the eigen space of $-1$. It yields $\dim(E(-1))\geq \lfloor (n+1)/2\rfloor-1=\lfloor n/2\rfloor$. 

Since $\lceil  n/2\rceil+\lfloor n/2\rfloor=n$, the characteristical polynomial is
$$ (X-1)^{\lceil  n/2\rceil}(X+1)^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$$